# Trying to update a list by changing a variable

Tags: python

So i have a grid right so lets say

```
cols_count, rows_count=5, 5
Matrix = [[0 for x in range(cols_count)] for y in range(rows_count)]
```

then lets say i have specific points on the grid that i want to change easily so we'll go for all the corners

```
pos_0_0 = Matrix[0][0]
pos_4_0 = Matrix[4][0]
pos_0_4 = Matrix[0][4]
pos_4_4 = Matrix[4][4]
```

how would i go about initialising pos_0_0 so that when it changes, the value of Matrix[0][0] also changes? is there a way to do this?

Comment: You cannot change a value by reassigning a name (that points to that value) to another value. The best you can do is to create a _special_ object to act as a value and provide it an update method.

Comment: so you cant have two variables that point to the same memory location in python?

Comment: I think [this article](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) (or in the form of a [presentation](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names1.html)) might be helpful. Python doesn't really have variables the way say C does, it's all references. If you do `pos_0_0 = 1`, you do not change the value, you rebind the reference to point to `1`.